# IsPostBack returns always false when using urlrewriting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I created a very small web app. I want to use clean urls but if i use urlrewriting I can't reach PageMethods. I'm trying to reach PageMethods from a JavaScript file but isPostBack returns false and it just refreshes the page.

If i don't use urlrewriting it works perfectly and writes whatever i want to the writeHere div.

What could it be the problem ?

This is the **ANCHOR** that calls js function

```
Test <a href="#" onclick = "testjs('test');">HERE</a>. 
<div id = "writeHere"></div>
```

This is the **JS FUNCTION** that calls PageMethods

```
function testjs(test) {
document.getElementById("writeHere").innerHTML = "";

PageMethods.messi(test,CallSuccess,CallFailed);

function CallSuccess(res) {
    document.getElementById("writeHere").innerHTML = res.toString();
}

function CallFailed(res) {
   document.getElementById('writeHere').innerHTML = "ERROR";
   }
}
```

Here the **MESSI METHOD** of the aspx file

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string messi(string test)
{
    return test; 
}
```

And finally this is the **REWRITING RULE**

```
<rewriter>
<rewrite url="~/(.+).aspx" to="~/uso/$1.aspx" processing ="stop"/>
</rewriter>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what rewriting engine you are using, make sure the query string is also carried over to rewritten URL. If `PageMethods.messi` is using GET verb to send the request, parameters informing that it is postback are in the query string.